# "Rolling" Deployments to numerous windows workstations

Tags: software-development, installer

Previously, we have been using ClickOnce to deploy a certain piece of software (developed in-house) to our Windows workstations.

We're looking for an alternative that will let us "roll" the application updates, so only a few selected computers get the software updated each day, to theoretically limit the impact of any bugs that make it through testing.

Does such a system exist, or would we need to roll our own?